# Internet entirely unable to work

Tags: networking, internet, internet-connection

Lately, my computer has had trouble connecting to the internet. I'm completely unable to do any work I need to do, etc. This has gone on for 2 weeks. Occasionally, it will work for about 3 minutes but then stops working again. My computer is a desktop PC and not a laptop.

Here's what I've gathered from tampering with it:

- My computer cannot connect to a wired or unwired connection (I think)
- My computer does not display a yellow warning sign when it's unable to connect.
- The main error I am receiving is 'server DNS address cannot be found'.
- It says I am connected without any problems when I get the above error. When it says I am connected my browser *and* internet are not working.

So, I don't really know what to do because it says I'm connected. Though, I suppose this final point might help answers: **other devices are able to connect completely fine.**

Is there any way to fix my problem? Thanks.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DanielCann-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : home

Wireless LAN adapter Local Area Connection* 3:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 38-2C-4A-46-A3-26
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 38-2C-4A-E8-24-D4
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::5ded:730f:8516:c5b5%4(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.94(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 1, 2016 7:58:43 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 2, 2016 7:58:43 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 238562378
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-62-3C-20-38-2C-4A-E8-24-D4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : ASUS PCE-N15 11n Wireless LAN PCI-E Card
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 38-2C-4A-46-A3-26
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a13f:deef:5f08:2cdd%8(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.77(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, October 1, 2016 8:55:21 AM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Sunday, October 2, 2016 9:09:05 AM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 272116810
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1C-62-3C-20-38-2C-4A-E8-24-D4
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.home:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

Update:

My internet is now functional for about 5 minutes after I restart my computer. It then goes strange, and gives me a 'Server DNS Adress could not be found' error. The troubleshooter is not able to fix it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: What operating system is your computer using? You can manually configure it to use, say Google's DNS: [Configure your network settings to use Google Public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using). After that, you really should scan your computer for malware, as some sorts mess up your network settings as one of the bad things they do.

Comment: I'm using windows 10 - I'll scan my computer now

Comment: It's worth using a second malware scanner too - Malwarebytes is a popular and fairly effective one.

Comment: Have you tried another browser?

Comment: Yes, I have tried Firefox and Microsoft edge as well as google chrome

Comment: @DavidPostill I provided an update edit regarding the stage I have reached.

Comment: @MartinCann When your computer *can* reach the Internet, is there a value in the "Default Gateway" field as shown in `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: In the default gateway field there are only 2 colons following the colon after the line of dots, no numbers. @AndrewMorton

Comment: @MartinCann If you know the IP address of your router on the internal network (from what I can see it is probably 192.168.1.254) then you can manually set the "Default Gateway" to that.

Comment: How do I find that out? And how could I set it?

Comment: @MartinCann If your router has a configuration page that you access through a browser, the IP address is very likely to be in the address bar in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there any way to fix my problem?

Try reinitialising the network states. Run the following commands in a `cmd` shell (you may need to be an Adminstrator).

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh winsock reset catalog
  ```
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh int ip reset reset.log
  ```
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  ```
  netsh advfirewall reset
  ```
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  ```
  ipconfig /flushdns
  ```
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  ```
  ipconfig /registerdns
  ```
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  ```
  route /f
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I followed your and @Brady Osborne advice, and things seem to be working. I'll see how it holds out.

Comment: @MartinCann Great. If this or another answer was helpful to you and answered your question, please don't forget to [accept that answer](http://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: This hasn't worked, and I'm still getting the same errors. I also tried @Brady Osborne advice. It says I am connected with a secure connection but I am still unable to access the Internet. Do you have any other ideas on what I can try?

Comment: @MartinCann Please edit the question and include the output from `ipconfig /all`

Comment: I have provided the output in a suggested edit @DavidPostill

Answer (score 0):

What DavidPostill said should work.

You might also perform the following command and report on the DNS servers configured:

```
ipconfig /all
```

You may consider changing your DNS servers from automatic to a publicly, well-known, and reliable DNS server service such as Google which is 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4, or OpenDNS which is 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.220.220.