# Why has my Windows 7 machine stopped being able to connect to internet via home network?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My Windows 7 machine, which has been wirelessly connecting to the internet via my home network without trouble for a long time, has suddenly become unable to reach the internet in this way. I can still connect to my wireless network, but Windows identifies it as an "Unidentified network" with "No Internet access".

However:

- I can connect to the internet using my home network using a wired (ethernet cable) connection.
- I can connect to the internet using public wifi spots at restaurants and cafes (including those requiring passwords).
- Other devices in my house (e.g., smart phones, tablets, Roku box) continue to reach the internet via my wireless home network.
- Guests who come over have no trouble accessing the internet via my wifi network.

Also:

- There have been no configuration changes or software updates made to my router (D-Link DIR-655).
- None of the Windows Network Diagnostics troubleshooter, the Windows Internet Connections troubleshooter and the Windows Network Adapter troubleshooter are able to resolve the problem.
- Rebooting the machine and the router doesn't solve the problem.
- Following the steps at [Internet entirely unable to work](https://superuser.com/questions/1130144/internet-entirely-unable-to-work) briefly made the problem go away, but after rebooting the computer, the problem came back.

Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue?

OS Details: Windows 7 Professional 64-bit with SP1 and all "important" updates installed.

Comment: Try the suggestions in my answer to [Internet entirely unable to work](//superuser.com/a/1130147)

Comment: Are you using DHCP or a static IP when connecting to the Wi-Fi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Internet entirely unable to work](http://superuser.com/questions/1130144/internet-entirely-unable-to-work)

Comment: @Ramhound: Note that the computer has no trouble reaching the internet using McDonald's wifi, so it's not the case that the internet is entirely unable to work. It just doesn't work on my home wifi network.  (My computer also connects to the internet via my home network when connected via ethernet cable.)

Comment: @DavidPostill: Nothing worked until I got to the last step (route /f), but that did the trick. Thanks! Can you explain what the problem on my machine was, i.e., why I had internet connectivity via wifi at McDonald's and why I had internet connectivity via ethernet cable at my house (as I noted in my reply to Ramhound, but failed to note in my original question), but why I had no internet connectivity via wifi at my house?

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe No idea. Something screwed up your routing table. Probably McD :)

Comment: In this case, McD is a good guy. The fact that things worked there was what let me know that they *could* work! Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe - You didn't mention that in your question.

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the situation. Briefly, wired access works, and wifi access at public access points works. Other devices work on my wifi network. The only problem is with this one computer on my wifi network.